# admin approve/reject in one document

Tags: c#, asp.net

i done with approve/reject documents  but there is a problem

suppose there is a 3 documents in grid view when admin login and want to approve/reject only 1 document i.e docid 81 and click on submit button then data save in database

approval table

```
**seqno docid approveid  approveby**
79     14      3       john
80     16      3       john
81     17      2      john
```

but in my code
 when admin approve/reject only 1 (i.e 81 docid) document whereas admin not worked in others two then admin click on submit button then other two documents data are also save in approval (i.e 79,80 docid)table ..why this happened?

here is submit button code

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string connStr = 
        ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["mydms"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection mySQLconnection = new SqlConnection(connStr);
        if (mySQLconnection.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
        {
            mySQLconnection.Open();
        }

        foreach (GridViewRow row in GrdFileApprove.Rows)
        {

            if (row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {
                DropDownList DropDownListcontrol = row.FindControl("DropDownList4") as
             DropDownList;
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("approveddd", mySQLconnection);
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;                
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@DocID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = 
              Convert.ToInt32((row.Cells[1].Text));
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@ApproveID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = 
               Convert.ToInt32(DropDownListcontrol.SelectedValue);
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@ApproveBy", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = 
               (Session["Login2"]);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                DMSLIB.Doc myDoc = new DMSLIB.Doc();
                myDoc.MarkDocAs(Convert.ToInt16(row.Cells[1].Text), Convert.ToInt32(DropDownListcontrol.SelectedValue));


            }
            else
            {
                apfi.Text = "Error";
            }
        }


        if (mySQLconnection.State == ConnectionState.Open)
        {
            mySQLconnection.Close();
        }
```

any help?

Comment: FYI.. this code `cmd.Parameters.Add("@DocID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = 
              Convert.ToInt32((row.Cells[1].Text))` will can crash the update in case of invalid input

Comment: Looks like you loop thu all rows and save them all, don't you?

Comment: Also, check your stored proc for WHERE clause

Answer (score 0):

You loop thru ALL rows and run stored proc for every item.

Comment: @user2931015 you probably need to process only a single row containing pressed button